# airflow: Email Configuration

Tags: python, airflow

I am scheduling a task to send email from Airflow 2.1.1.
I have correctly configured the smtp parameters in the airflow.cfg file

```
smtp_host = mr.my_domain.com
smtp_starttls = False
smtp_ssl = True
smtp_user = email@my_domain.com
smtp_password = ********
smtp_port = 465
smtp_mail_from = email@my_domain.com
smtp_timeout = 30
smtp_retry_limit = 5
```

If I test the task from the cli, the emails are sent correctly but I get the following alert message:

```
..../lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py:101 PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.
```

From the GUI the message is:

```
INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
```

So I am trying to create a connection as stated in the documentation:

```
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html
```

*To configure SMTP credentials, create a connection called smtp_default, or choose a custom connection name and set it in email_conn_id.*

But when creating a new connection, SMTP is not present among the options.

I hope you can give me a hand, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs about email configurations were updated recently by this [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16523). Since you are viewing the stable version of the docs it's not reflected there until the next Airflow version release.

> If you do not want to store the SMTP credentials in the config or in
> the environment variables, you can create a connection called
> `smtp_default`, or choose a custom connection name and set the
> `email_conn_id` with it's name in the configuration & store SMTP
> username-password in it. Other SMTP settings like host, port etc
> always gets picked up from the configuration only. The connection can
> be of any type (for example 'HTTP connection').

I think what possibly confuse you is the change made in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13601) added the :

```
# Email connection to use

email_conn_id = smtp_default
```

to `airflow.cfg` this was done since there are several services that can send emails (smtp/SES/Sendgrid setc..) it needed to be standardized.